# Can two windows be active at the same time?

Tags: interface

I'm working with two monitors in Blender 2.70 on Mac OS 10.9.2. Now when I add a second window by Shift Leftclick on a split area, only one of this windows is active and expects direct input. This is a big problem, since anytime I want do do something in the not active window, I have to click once in the window to make it active before I can start editing something.

• Is this OS specific? I tried to deactivate all of apples new multi monitor enhancements, but the problem still exists.

• Is there a user setting I missed? None of the tutorials I found on the web so far mentioned this problem nor how to solve it.

Thanks!

Edit: The best solution I found so far for Mac OS is a tool called "Zooom/2" which allows, amongst other things, to automatically focus on the window under your mouse cursor after a given time. The default is 0.25 seconds. This seems to work, but I'm not sure how I like it on a daily basis. I'll evaluate for a while. I found this in an other thread called: "How to focus on different windows across multi-monitors to hit a hotkey?"

However, this should be something that could be handled by Blender itself. It works just fine with Cinema 4d. There's an option that allows you to define a second window as a "Main Window" as well. After doing that you can click and edit anything in that second window without first activating it.

Comment: This is probably just the way OS X works, most Operating systems/DEs that I have used have this issue (I have not used OS X though, so this is an assumption on my part). In KDE there is an option to have window focus follow the mouse, but it takes a little getting used to outside of blender. The only good workaround I have found so far is to use one window stretched across both monitors (though I'm not absolutely sure you can do that with OS X, I don't have a mac to test with).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, gandalf3. Stretching the window over multiple monitors actually works quite well on the Mac. The problem with this is that my monitors are of different size and resolution. This means that either a big part of my window is hidden and not accessible or I'm wasting a lot of space on the bigger monitor. Unfortunately the smaller one is a rather cheap monitor and can't be used in portrait mode.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about it's a limitation of current Operating Systems.

Comment: You can also switch between windows of one application with `Cmd + ~` if you don't want to have to use your mouse.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal for different windows of a window manager to not get input (from the keyboard or mouse). That is, only one of them can be focused; and having the focus means that it gets keyboard and mouse input. Different applications can still get mouse and keyboard events however when they are aware of the other window: they can explicitly ask the window manager to still receive events. In the case of blender these aren't even two different applications; so I'm inclined to call it a bug of blender: blender should be aware where both windows are, and when the  mouse hovers over a split area of a window that doesn't have focus *still* process hot keys for that area. Blender could do the 'focus' part internally thus, and not care which of its windows has focus in the eyes of the window manager.