# Dual Monitors options?

Tags: interface

i really like Bleander 3d currently i use Autodesk Smoke to do my postwork but im thinking of going full blender. though the windows tend to get cluttered i would love to see the gui have a dual screen option if it already does could someone inform me on how to activate it. thanks

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21560/new-window-without-creating-a-new-screen-object

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23704/is-it-possible-to-make-the-default-scene-fill-two-monitors-at-startup  and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8379/can-two-windows-be-active-at-the-same-time